# Avoid blue flash behavior when reusing submenu of main menu as context menu

Tags: cocoa, menu, contextmenu, reusability

I have the following problem: In an Cocoa app, a submenu is defined and attached in the main menu. Now I need the exact same submenu as a context menu for a `NSView`.

Now, my goal is to avoid creating an exact duplicate of the main menu. I thought that I could reuse the already existing submenu. Indeed, I can just assign the corresponding menu to the `NSView` with Interface Builder and that seems to work.

But unfortunately, every time I select an item in the context menu now, the corresponding root main menu item flashes blue.

Is there any way to disable this behaviour? Or do you have other suggestions how this problem can be solved without duplicating the existing submenu?